# How do I add the last typed number to a total?

Tags: c#, math, numbers

I'm new to learning C# and I was wondering how to keep adding numbers I type to a total number. Right now instead of adding up all the numbers I typed in before typing 0, it just takes the last typed in number... The number count does go up however, which is why I'm pretty confused.

For example:

Enter number: 2

Enter number: 6

Enter number: 4

Enter number: 7

Enter number: 0

There are 4 positive numbers (Works like I intended)

The total amount is 7 (Is supposed to be 2+6+4+7 = 21)

```
Console.Write("Enter number: ");
string numberInput = Console.ReadLine();
double number = double.Parse(numberInput);

int count = 0;
double begin = 0;
double total = 0;

while (number != 0)
{
    if (number >= 0)
    {
        count++;
        total = begin + number;
    }
    Console.Write("Enter number: ");
    number = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
double average = total / count;
Console.WriteLine("There are {0} positive numbers", count);
Console.WriteLine("The total amount is {0}", total);
Console.WriteLine("Your average is: {0}", average);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: `total = begin + number;` -- `begin` is always 0, so `begin + number` is always `0 + number`, so `total` is always equal to whatever the last number was.

Comment: If you want to begin at `begin` , initialize `total` with it instead `double begin = 0;
double total = begin;`. And then sum up with `total += number;`

Comment: You may want to consider using `double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number)`. Otherwise entering a non-numeric value will throw an exception. [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out already, had to change this:

```
total = begin + number;
```

to

```
total = total + number;
```

Comment: `total = total + number` can be rewritten as `total += number`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `begin` variable as you can sum input values like below:

```
total += number; // This is the same with 'total = total + number;'
```

As a suggestion, you can improve your code using `do while` loop like below:

```
int count = 0;
double total = 0;
double number;

do
{
    Console.Write("Enter number: ");
    number = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (number > 0)
    {
        count++;
        total += number;
    }
} while (number != 0);

double average = total / count;
Console.WriteLine("There are {0} positive numbers", count);
Console.WriteLine("The total amount is {0}", total);
Console.WriteLine("Your average is: {0}", average);
Console.ReadKey();
```